# Update existing object in Core Data with reference to NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I fetched the objects in an core data entity. Then I cross check with a NSArray and find out what are the existing objects in the data base. 
Then I insert new objects to database. I am struggling in how to update existing objects in this code. Please help me to do it in best way.

```
// get manageObjectContext
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSArray *arrIds = [arr valueForKeyPath:@"anId"];

NSError *error;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SomeEntity"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K IN %@", @"anId", arrIds];

NSArray *existingItems = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

//Get the existing ids:
NSArray *existingIds = [existingItems valueForKeyPath:@"anId"];

for (NSDictionary *item in arr) {
    if ([existingItems containsObject:topic[@"anId"]]) {
        // update exsising item
    }
    else{
        // Insert new items done .........
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code!!

AppDelegate *appDelegate =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context =
[appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entityDesc =
[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Qr_code"
            inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDesc];

NSPredicate *pred =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(user_ID=%@)",
 kText];
[request setPredicate:pred];
matches = nil;

NSError *error;
updatedata = [context executeFetchRequest:request
                                     error:&error];

if ([updatedata count] == 0) {

} else {
    matches=updatedata[0];

}
```